# PHP Instagram Api User Logout?

Tags: php, url, instagram

I'm working on a way to log my user out of my instagram application. Is there a way to do this while redirecting to my homepage and not to the instagram's logout page (https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/)  I'm using the [cosenary PHP API wrapper](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would open the instagram logout page in a hidden iframe like this:

```
$(body).append('<div style="display:none"><iframe src="https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/" width="0" height="0"></iframe></div>');
```

Comment: Ah, that sounds very good. How would I make that a clickable link?

Comment: put the above in a `function logout(){..}` and use `onclick="logout()"`