# How to Logout from Instagram API in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication, instagram, logout, instagram-api

I logged in Instagram using browser with API. I want to logout from the Instagram API. How can i logout from Instagram API programmatically?

Comment: Just clear out the access tokens you have stored for that user.

Answer (score 0):

Open the instagram logout page in an hidden iframe, that will logout user from Insatgram: `https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/`

Here is answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23280778/423089

Comment: Instagram's headers prevent iframing of the site via the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header. This answer is highly unlikely to work.

Comment: @ceejayoz btw, you cannot just down vote, just cause you think its highly unlikely to work, try it and make sure first :)